# Laravel 7 one blade component using both a variable and static information

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

In Laravel 7 I'd like to use one [anonymous Blade component](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#anonymous-components) that can accept both dynamic and static values as properties. The below code should explain what I mean:

```
// Scenario 1: dynamic values

<x-alert :type="session('alert.type')" :dismissable="session('alert.dismissable')">
  {{ session('alert.body') }}
</x-alert>


// Scenario 2: static values

<x-alert :type="'success'" :dismissable="'yes'">
  {{ $status }}
</x-alert>
```

And the component

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ $type }} {{ $dismissable == 'yes' ? 'alert-dismissible' : '' }} fade show" role="alert">

    {!! $slot !!}

    @if($dismissable == 'yes')
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
            <i class="fal fa-times"></i>
        </button>
    @endif

</div>
```

Now this works fine, but my question is: is the right way to do it when you want to tick all these boxes:

- Use an anonymous component
- Pass both static or dynamic variables for the same property (like `:type` and `:dismissable` in the example)

The documentation isn't fully clear on this.

Comment: could you please clarify the question? You could probably pass strings like this `<x-alert type="success" dismissable="yes">`

Comment: I have added clarification in the question. What you're suggesting doesn't work if you pass dynamic variables like in my first example, like session data or just `$variable`. In order to make dynamic data work you need to do `:type` and `:dismissable` (note the semi-colon). But with the semi-colon, you need to pass static data with singles quotes, so then you have both double and single quotes. It's a bit difficult to explain in this comment, but the examples in my question should clearly indicate the difference and how it works.

Comment: I think, I've understood you. You don't have to pick one, you can use both depending what values you're passing at the moment. Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah that was a lot easier than I thought :-). Thanks for the clear answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decide whether to pass a value via HTML attribute or `:` prefixed attribute when you use the component.

If the component receives a dynamic value, use, as you mentioned:

```
<x-alert :type="session('alert.type')" :dismissable="session('alert.dismissable')">
 {{ session('alert.body') }}
</x-alert>
```

If the component receives a primitive value like a hardcoded string use HTML attribute without `:` prefix and single quotes inside:

```
<x-alert type="success" dismissable="yes">
  {{ $status }}
</x-alert>
```

In both cases `$type` and `$dismissable` variables would be available in your component.